# Is there anyway to have vim not count special characters as words?

Tags: vim, macros, gvim

I'm using VIM do alot of work for me using the macros.

There's alot of text in columns and I want the macro to move between columns effortlessly by pressing the w key to "move to the beginning of the next word"

For example:

```
DataSourceName            string                       ""   
DetailFields              []string                          
DynamicControlBorder      boolean                 empty  may be void 
EscapeProcessing          boolean                    True   
FetchDirection            long                       1000   
FetchSize                 long                         12   
Filter                    string                       ""   
GroupBy                   string                       ""   
HavingClause              string                       ""
```

However when I do this, VIM only does this for letters; whenever it encounters a "[" or a " it interprets this as another word, messing up the macro because it now appears that there is an additional column.

Is there any setting I can change to make vim ignore the special characters and treat them just like the letters by skipping over them?

Comment: This is borderline a http://stackoverflow.com question since it's mostly programmers who use vim, you'll have better luck getting it answered there.

Comment: @cma Okay moved question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182012/is-there-anyway-to-have-vim-not-count-special-characters-as-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the definition of a word in vim by using

```
:set iskeyword=<specification>
```

Remeber to change it back, though, when you have finished with the special usage.

```
:set iskeyword?
```

will show the current usage. My terminal responds with

> iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255

for all the letters a-z and A-Z (@), digits 0 to 9 (ASCII 48-57), underscore and international letters (ASCII 192-255)

Comment: Wow that's a better answer then I got over on Stackoverflow (almost the same but better!  Thanks!